# Webdriverio Error on Window10 basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')") ^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

When i try to run npm run  then i got below error 
I am using below configuration :

webdriverio v4.14.4

node v8.5

npm v5.3

Windows 10

below is my config file

```
"scripts":{
"web": "node node_modules/.bin/wdio ./test/config/suite.web.conf.js",
}
```

below error :

```
> $ npm run web
>  tconnect-uiautomation@1.1.5 web >C:\Users\user\Downloads\webdriverioFramework\webdriverioFramework 
>ENV=preprod node node_modules/.bin/wdio ./test/config/suite.web.conf.js

C:\Users\user\Downloads\webdriverioFramework\webdriverioFramework\node_modules\.bin\wdio:2
> basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
>           ^^^^^^^
> 
> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>     at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
>     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:588:28)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
>     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:201:16)
>     at bootstrap_node.js:626:3 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1
```

Answer (score 13):

I got the solution for this error :

i had to remove only "**node**" from the config file .

new config looks like :

```
"scripts":{
"web": "node_modules/.bin/wdio ./test/config/suite.web.conf.js",
}
```

just removed "**node**" from the script .